# C# & SQL Server improvement

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got multiple selects from C# to one table in SQL Server in one time period through a stored procedure. That's correct, but that's slow and I'd like to improve that, now.

This is my C# code:

```
while (startDate!= endDate)
{
    var anyDay_CntPost = 0;
    anyDay_CntPost = db.GetPostCount(1, tmpDate).Select(x => x.cntPost).FirstOrDefault().Value;

    if (anyDay_CntPost != 0)
    {
        var anyDay_cnt1 = db.GetPostCount(1, tmpDate).Select(x => x.cntPost).FirstOrDefault().Value; ;
        var anyDay_cnt2 = db.GetPostCount(2, tmpDate).Select(x => x.cntPost).FirstOrDefault().Value;
        var anyDay_cnt3 = db.GetPostCount(3, tmpDate).Select(x => x.cntPost).FirstOrDefault().Value;

        listCount.arr1.Add(anyDay_cnt1);
        listCount.arr2.Add(anyDay_cnt2);
        listCount.arr3.Add(anyDay_cnt3);
    }

    startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
}
```

And this is the stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPostCount]
    @type int,
    @date nvarchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ----<<-----------------------------
    if @type = 1
    begin
        SELECT cntPost = count(*) 
        FROM Post 
        WHERE Date = @date AND type = 1
    end

    ---<<------------------------------
    if @type = 1
    begin
        SELECT cntPost = count(*) 
        FROM Post 
        WHERE Date = @date and type = 2
    end
    ---<<------------------------------
    if @type = 2
    begin
        SELECT cntPost = count(*) 
        FROM Post 
        WHERE Date = @date and type = 3
    end
End
```

My result is:

```
____________________________________________ 
|    Date    | Count 1 | Count 2 | Count 3 |  
 ------------------------------------------
| 10/25/2015 |   200   |  360    |   547   |
| 10/24/2015 |   185   |  326    |   132   |
| 10/23/2015 |   100   |  490    |   670   |
 ------------------------------------------
```

I want optimize the above code, because it's too slow and tardy. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Well, I would just fetch all the days and types with one select, and I would use proper data types, like date for dates and not nvarchar(max)

Comment: Can you try something like `Where Date = @date and type in (1,2,3)` and `group by type` ?

Comment: @M22an I don't can. I pass one of kind "type" every time.

Comment: please no vote down me.

Comment: @JamesZ I don't understand! please vote up me.

Comment: why not get records back between start and enddate? then do your processing in code? you get the records back in one hit (less hits to the DB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution would be the following procedure:

```
create procedure [dbo].[GetPostCount]
    @startdate date,
    @enddate date
as
    select Date, Type, count(*) as cntPost
    from Post 
    where Date >= @startdate and Date <= @enddate and Type in (1, 2, 3)
    group by Date, Type
```

You just select all data that you need once and then use it in your while loop. Now you are querying database 4 times in each iteration and of course it is slow.